# Delphi 7 - Informar Certificado A3 em Indy HTTP

Tags: delphi, web-service, certificado-digital, openssl, indy-10

Olá,
Estou tentando e sem sucesso até agora realizar a integração com um web service, onde uso o componente Indy HTTP, atualizado para a versão 10 no Delphi 7 para acessar e fazer um GET utilizando XML e JSON em um Web Service REST, porém é necessário utilizar o certificado digital, que está em um Token A3 que não é possível exportar para um arquivo .cer com a chave privada.

Eu consigo ler o token do certificado utilizando as libs e DLLs do CAPICOM, porém não consigo informar para o IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL usar o certificado.

Pelo que pesquisei, me parece que é necessário enviar o dado como CustomHeader, porém nunca utilizei desta forma, alguém já conseguiu realizar algo do tipo?

O WS que preciso acessar é este: https://val.portalunico.siscomex.gov.br/due/api/ext/due

O curioso é que acessando da maquina que estou com certificado recebo o erro 401 Unauthorized, o mesmo que recebo ao realizar o envio com o IdHTTP, porém em outra máquina sem o certificado instalado recebo um erro diferente, " No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header"

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar um certificado A3 ao componente TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125207/adicionar-um-certificado-a3-ao-componente-tidssliohandlersocketopenssl)